# trying to intergrate STRIPE payment gateway to my website on s3

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, token, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate STRIPE payment gateway to my website.
This website will be hosted on AWS S3 instance.

I tried checkout option from this
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom
and 
https://stripe.com/docs/charges

I am losing the track in between.

Does anyone have a sequential flow for  the same.
can anyone tell me how to create a token as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately there is no direct way to use Stripe API in a static website (hosted in Amazon S3 or wherever). Because Stripe API needed server side integration like (PHP, nodejs, java or whatever).**

For security reasons, Stripe doesn’t allow to make his solution works without server’s side code (to handle the payment process).

Stripe give this token back to you and after that you can perform any operation you want using Stripe API (create new order, pay a new charge, create a customer, …) by manipulating this only token (and not the real Credit Card number).

So, it is normal that you have lost your track to see Stripe API docs.

> It is better to add a simple server to integrate Stripe API call in your side.

**But some way around**

You can find some online services that will do your server side thing which can resolve your problem.

[Here](https://medium.com/startup-grind/use-stripe-without-a-back-end-server-in-less-than-5-minutes-d96f9883c51a) is an example way around to use Stripe in static website.
You can find lot of alternative options to do it!

**But remember use third party services to do your server side job**

1. You will have to expose your Stripe API KEY to other place.
2. If you think it is safe to expose Stripe API KEY to other place than your website. Then it is okay. But it is not safe at all.